# angularjs filter customize by name and date

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in `angularjs` so I need your help :)

I have a `json` data like this

```
data = [{"start_date": "sampledate1", "end_date":"sampledate1", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name1"}
},{"start_date": "sampledate2", "end_date":"sampledate2", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name1"}
},{"start_date": "sampledate1", "end_date":"sampledate1", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name2"}
},{"start_date": "sampledate2", "end_date":"sampledate2", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name2"}
}]
```

I need to see this in view like this

```
name1
start_date - end_date
name2
start_date - end_date
```

I try `groupby` name but my `date` is not working??

Comment: What you exactly want to do? Show the data as you specified?

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular. So, save the data in `$scope`:

```
$scope.data = [{"start_date": "sampledate1", "end_date":"sampledate1", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name1"}
},{"start_date": "sampledate2", "end_date":"sampledate2", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name1"}
},{"start_date": "sampledate1", "end_date":"sampledate1", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name2"}
},{"start_date": "sampledate2", "end_date":"sampledate2", "employee":{"id":1, "name":"Name2"}
}]
```

In view:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in data | unique'>
  {{item.employee.name}}<br>
  {{item.start_date}}
  {{item.end_date}}
</div>
```

I have written a custom filter.

```
.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(collection) {
      var output = [], 
          keys = [];
      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
          var key = item.employee.name;
          if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key); 
              output.push(item);
          }
      });
      return output;
   };
});
```

Using that filter in your `ng-repeat` using `| unique`

All the best.

Comment: please check your code once its $sscope.data in js and datasof in html

Comment: @SaEChowdary, Thanks.

Comment: but the OP asked that he dont want dup's and he's trying with group by ......but your answer provide Dup's.....do u know that??

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry for the late raply.... i dont understand your customize filter is that jquery???

Comment: It is angularjs @wiwit

Comment: in my console said filter is not define